# std::map losing track of my data?

Tags: c++, dictionary, reference, pass-by-reference

I'm sticking some data, wrapped with boost::any into a map in a class method getValue.  Everything works fine, the data is in the map as appropriate etc etc in getValue.  The second I leave getValue and try to use this data, it's no longer in the map.

This has me stumped, I'm probably forgetting to use a reference at a key spot, but I can't find it.

The relevant code is as follows:

test.c
     //We don't want to actually document the timer, the user can do that if he wants to.
      timeval tmp;

```
  tmp.tv_sec = 0;
  tmp.tv_usec = 0;

  gettimeofday(&tmp, NULL);
  getValue<timeval>(timerName) = tmp;
  std::cout << tmp.tv_usec << " : " << getSingleton().globalValues.count(key) << std::endl; //Count returns 0 here, for a given key X_X
```

test.h

```
 /* Grab the value of type T found while parsing.  Should use checkValue first.*/
  template<typename T>
  static T& getValue(const char* identifier) {
    //Used to ensure we have a valid value
    T tmp;
    //Used to index into the globalValues map
    std::string key = std::string(identifier);
    std::map<std::string, boost::any>& gmap = getSingleton().globalValues;

    if(checkValue(identifier)) //If we have the option, set it's value
      tmp = getSingleton().vmap[identifier].as<T>();  //vmap is correct, it specifies default values passed in via command line.  

    //We may have whatever is on the commandline, but what if
    //The programmer has made modifications?
    if(!gmap.count(key))  //The programmer hasn't done anything, lets register it then
      gmap[key] = boost::any(tmp);

    std::cout << "gmap " << key << std::endl;        
    std::cout << getSingleton().globalValues.count(key) << std::endl; //count returns 1 here, for a given key.
    return boost::any_cast<T&>(gmap[key]);
  }
```

...

test.h

```
 //Map of global values, stored here instead of in OptionsHierarchy
  //For ease of implementation
  std::map<std::string, boost::any> globalValues;
```

Comment: Returning a reference to a local variable???

Comment: It would sound like that, 'return boost::any_cast<T&>(gmap[key]);' returns a reference to the value stored in boost::any.

Comment: you are doing a any_cast to a reference of T of your map gmap, which is a local variable... (the value in your map also local) that is returning your local map by reference (out of scope) to your caller...

Comment: @Tony `gmap` is a reference to a global map. Everything in it should still be valid outside the function scope.

Comment: What is your definition of getSingleton? Is there any chance it is returning a copy of the map instead of a reference to it?

Comment: No, getSingleton returns a reference to the singleton object which actually owns globalValues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this, note how I define key in getValue as being std::string(identifier).  In test.c I was defining key as sanitizeString(..) which returned a different key, obviously.  Of course you guys couldn't see that so my bad.

Answer (score 0):

On these lines you use `vmap` instead of `gmap`. Is that right?

```
if(checkValue(identifier)) //If we have the option, set it's value
  tmp = getSingleton().vmap[identifier].as<T>();
```

Also I noticed that you're using `count` to check for existence of an item. Generally speaking unless you actually need the count, that will result in doing more work than `find` although for `std::map` it may be smart enough to optimize `count` into `find`. Since you want to insert if it doesn't exist and no-op when it does, just use `insert` as that's exactly the behavior `insert` will give you.

Comment: vmap is just for optional default values defined via command line.

Comment: For `std::map`, using `count` is the more readable way to check for membership. It is obviously at least as efficient as `find` since `count` is implemented with the knowledge that it can return only `0` or `1`.